# How to represent weighted nuclear norm of matrix variable X and minimize it by CVX function, or solve it by other possible packages

Tags: cvx

I want to minimize $f(x) = \mathrm{Tr}(\sqrt{\mathbf{X}^{T}\mathbf{X}}\mathbf{A})$, where $\mathbf{X}$ is an matrix variable of dimension $d \times d$, and $\mathbf{A}$ is a known matrix. I tried the following code:

```
cvx_begin
    variable x(d,d)
    minimize(trace(sqrt(sum_square_abs(x))*A)) 
    subject to
        x(sp_index) == M(sp_index)
cvx_end
```

However, there are still errors as following:

```
Error using cvx/sqrt (line 61)
Disciplined convex programming error:
Illegal operation: sqrt( {convex} ).

Error in Test_CVX_Iterative_Optimal (line 34)
    minimize(trace(sqrt(sum_square_abs(x))*A))
```

So how should I solve this problem by CVX? Looking forward to your reply! 
I also asked the same question in the CVX forum
http://ask.cvxr.com/question/2894
but haven't got it solved yet. Wish anyone here is able to offer help!

---

Update:
Thanks to @DavidKetcheson , I should use `sqrtm()` rather than `sqrt`. To represent $\mathrm{Tr}(\sqrt{\mathbf{X}^T\mathbf{X}})$ I should use `trace_sqrtm(sum_square_abs(x))`. However, I need to represent $\mathrm{Tr}(\sqrt{\mathbf{X}^T\mathbf{X}}\mathbf{A})$, and I don't know how to represent it by a valid CVX expression.

---

I tried

```
minimize(trace(sqrtm(sum_square_abs(x))*A))
```

to replace `sqrt` in the original, but I got the following error

```
Undefined function 'schur' for input arguments of type 'cvx'.

Error in sqrtm (line 32)
[Q, T] = schur(A,'complex');  % T is complex Schur form.

Error in Test_WeightNucNorm (line 35)
        minimize(trace(sqrtm(sum_square_abs(x))*A))
```

---

I understand now that `sqrtm()` function is not implemented in CVX, so I have the error ' Undefined function 'schur' for input arguments of type 'cvx'.'. But my problem is still not solved.

---

I think I should use:

```
minimize(trace_sqrtm(sum_square_abs(x))*A)
```

But I still get error:

```
Error using cvx/trace_sqrtm (line 9)
Input must be affine.

Error in Test_WeightNucNorm (line 40)
        minimize(trace_sqrtm(sum_square_abs(x))*A)
```

---------- Important update
Thanks to @k20 , I made a mistake!! This is not the weighted nuclear norm of matrix $\mathbf{X}$, but the weighted trace of $\sqrt{\mathbf{X}^T\mathbf{X}}$!! Now my problem becomes that:**how to represent the weighted nuclear norm of a matrix $\mathbf{X}$, where $\mathbf{X}$ is CVX variable, $\mathbf{A}$ is a diagonal weight matrix.**  I tried to find a CVX function which give me all the singular values of variable $\mathbf{X}$, but I haven't found such a function.

Comment: The square root of an spd matrix is a matrix. How does it make sense to minimize a matrix expression?

Comment: Hi @Kirill , thanks for help! My previous question is aimed to simplified my question and show the key problem. I updated my question. Can you check it? Thanks!

Comment: @DavidKetcheson , sorry, A is outside the square root, I updated my question. Thanks for help!

Comment: Also, I think you mean `sqrtm()`, not `sqrt`.

Comment: @DavidKetcheson It is matrix muplication, just $X^{T}X$.

Comment: @DavidKetcheson I think it is still `sqrt`, as `sqrtm()` will give me a different kind of error. The background is: the nuclear norm of a matrix X is $nuc_norm(X)=trace(sqrt(X'*X))$ , but now I am not minimize the nuc_norm.

Comment: @Excalibur: I'm pretty sure you mean sqrtm not sqrt too, and according to http://scicomp.stackexchange.com/questions/5503 cvx has trace_sqrtm but this is not exactly what you need.

Comment: @DavidKetcheson Seems you are right! Thanks very much! But I am still have problem to solve it by CVX.

Comment: a question on math.stackexchange seems related http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/239352/trace-minimization-with-constraints

Comment: @k20 Thanks, seems related. I will looking into it!

Comment: @Excalibur I see in your other question that your function is called Test_WeightNucNorm.  If the nuc norm is trace_sqrtm(X' X) then is 'WeightNucNorm' trace(sqrtm(X' X) * A) where matrix A somehow involves weights?  Is it a diagonal matrix of non-negative weights?  If so, you could try sum(diag(sqrtm(X' X)) * diag(A)).

Comment: Oh right sqrtm is not in cvx.  But if A is a diagonal matrix of weights, what about something like trace_sqrtm((XA)'(XA))?

Comment: ...which would be norm_nuc(XA).

Comment: @k20 you are totally right! Yes, A is a diagnal non-negative weights matrix. However, `norm_nuc(X*A)` is not equivalent with `sum(diag(sqrtm(X' X)) * diag(A))`. What I need is the equivalent representation with `sum(diag(sqrtm(X' X)) * diag(A))`, but I haven't found a valid representation for CVX yet.

Comment: @Excalibur: you're right, my math was wrong.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm going to boldly say that you are doing it wrong, because your goal is to minimize a weighted nuclear norm but your equations don't agree.  The nuclear norm is the sum of singular values.  The weighted nuclear norm is the weighted sum of singular values.  If your matrix A is intended to be the diagonal matrix of singular value weights, then I don't think your equation represents the correct weighted sum.

The response to the question http://ask.cvxr.com/question/1708/maximize-the-minimum-singular-value/ suggests that the minimum singular value is not a convex or concave function so cvx can't deal with it.  Therefore it seems unlikely that cvx can deal with an arbitrary weighted sum of singular values, as would be required by a weighted nuclear norm.

Comment: Hi @k20 , as $norm_nuc(x)=trace(\sqrt{x^Tx})$, so that I think the weighted nuclear norm is $trace(\sqrt{x^Tx}*A)$ as $A$ is a diagonal weight matrix. Is this wrong? Thanks for your help!

Comment: Yes it is wrong.  Pick a matrix X and compute trace(sqrtm(X' X)) and you will see that this is the sum of the singular values s of X.  Then pick some weights w and define A as the corresponding diagonal matrix.  You will see that trace(sqrtm(X' X) * A) does not equal the weighted nuclear norm (the dot product of s with w), except in special cases like when A is the identity matrix.

Comment: An easy example is when X is diagonal.  The weighted nuclear norm should not be affected by permuting X but the thing that you are computing is affected.

Comment: Hi @k20 , oh, you are totally right! My mistake is: what I get is the weighted trace, not weighted nuclear norm!!

Comment: Hi @k20 , thanks very much!! Your observation is great! Now my problem should be how to represent the weighted nuclear norm ...

Comment: @Excalibur: As I mention in my answer, you can't represent the weighted nuclear norm in a way that cvx will solve it, because it is not convex or concave.  You will need to use a different method to solve the minimization.

Comment: Hi @k20 , thanks, so that I should refer to other possible ways to solve my problem.

Answer (score 1):

minimizing $\sqrt{f(x)}$ is equivalent to minimizing $f(x)$ as long as $f(x) \geq 0$ because taking the square root is a monotone transformation.  Just remove the square root from your objective function.

Comment: Hi @BrianBorchers, thanks for your help! I updated my question. My previous simplified question was aimed to show the key problem, but it leads a simple solution you mentioned. I need to minimize $trace(\sqrt{(X′X)}A)$, in this way, the $\sqrt{ } $ cannot be removed. Do you know how to express it by an expression that CVX will accept?

Comment: Sorry- I had misread your question as involving the square root of a scalar expression.